# Distributed Configuration with HashiCorp Consul and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, consul, spring-cloud-config

I wonder how to share some properties in HashiCorp Consul using Spring Boot, I read there's the dependency 'spring-cloud-consul-config' but I could not find how to load a folder with all properties files from there.

Using Spring Cloud Config Server this is possible, for example:

```
spring:  
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native: 
          searchLocations: file:C:/springbootapp/properties/
```

But, how to do it in Spring Cloud Config Consul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have consul running on a standard port there is not much configuration needed using spring boot. The whole code is pasted below (no other configuration files).

The tricky part for me was to figure out how key/values should be stored in consul in order to be visible by spring boot app. There is some information in documentation but it is a little bit misleading I think.

To answer your question I put the values under key "config/bootstrap/key1" inside consul to make the following example work.

Here is a sample code that worked for me:

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.M5</version>
</dependency>
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RestController
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return env.getProperty("key1");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(true).run(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Mateusz, I was able to read the properties from Consul if they're set on path /config/application/data, my goal is to publish from a local folder all properties files to Consul server such as Spring Config Server does using native profile. Is there any way for it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand: you would like to publish all properties from files to consul server during startup? If yes I don't think that was the goal of library. If it is not possible using the library I think it should be fairly easy to code using a consul client library.

Comment: Yes, that's it.. With Spring Cloud Config Server, this is possible... so I can share all my properties values my client applications.

Comment: The purpose of Spring Cloud Config Server and Spring Cloud Consul Config is slightly different. The first one is indeed used to serve the configuration to other applications (your app becomes a configuration server if you don't have a third party config server) while the second one provides you a way to connect to Consul (a third party configuration server). The idea is that Consul is already provided in your environment and primed with configuration. You can have one instance in dev environment and another in production with different set of values.